# Getting an HTML table row to take up maximum height

Tags: html, html-table, max, row

I've seen other similar questions on Stack Overflow, but my requirements seem more strict than usual and I didn't find an existing solution that worked. Without further ado, here's a hopefully self-explanatory fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mjomble/B47Ke/

Works just fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE. Screenshots from my system:

[image: Renderings in different browsers]

Note that the table contents are highly dynamic, so any solutions involving fixed width or height will probably not work. Even the number of columns is dynamic.
And since the dynamic column widths should match across many rows, I probably can't implement this without tables.

I see that jsfiddle links without actual code are not wanted on SO, so here's the HTML of the sample:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
            <div>Many lines here</div>
        </td>

        <td>The first two rows must take up minimal height.</td>
        <td>When the table gets narrow, the text must wrap.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Which takes up a little additional height.</td>
        <td>So I can't set a fixed height for these rows.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer">
        <td>Spacer rows like this must take up maximum height.</td>
        <td>With height: 100%, they do in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <div>More lines here</div>
            <div>More lines here</div>
            <div>More lines here</div>
            <div>More lines here</div>
            <div>More lines here</div>
            <div>More lines here</div>
            <div>More lines here</div>
            <div>More lines here</div>
        </td>

        <td>And that's not all! The cells on this row must</td>
        <td>have the same dynamic widths as the ones above.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>So we can't use fixed widths.</td>
        <td>And probably no nested tables either.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 4px 8px
}
tr.spacer td {
    height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout):

> CSS 2.1 does not specify how cells that span more than one row affect
>   row height calculations except that the sum of the row heights
>   involved must be great enough to encompass the cell spanning the rows.

And there does not seem to be anything new in CSS3 in this regard (but I may have missed it).

Note that in Safari at least, you don't actually need the `height: 100%` to get the expected result.